# immutablejs with modifiable nested properties yay or nay?

Tags: functional-programming, immutability, record, immutable.js

In the following I'm able to edit the property `map` of `dungeon` which is immutablejs Record type. If immutablejs doesn't immune deeper nested objs from being changed, is there a point at all in defining a structure such as the following?

```
const DungeonObj = Immutable.Record({
  map : [1,2,3]
});

class Dungeon {
  static someFunc(map) {
    map[0] = 'changed';
    return map;
  }
}

let dungeon = new DungeonObj();

console.log(Dungeon.someFunc(dungeon.map));
console.log(dungeon.map);
```

This will print:

```
["changed", 2, 3]
["changed", 2, 3]
```

Should I have defined `map` as a List instead? Does it makes sense to have deep nested immutable data types say a `Record` inside a `List` inside a `Map`?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that even though DungeonObj is immutable its internal props are not? I don't seem to be able to replace its props but I can change them! Is this even a valid practice? What should I do to make them all immutable? Use a nested List or Map inside a Record? Lots of questions :)

Comment: Ok I think I know the answer! basically here I'm not setting the props I'm changing them which to my surprise were allowed. Wondering if there is a point in having a `Record` with modifiable props of type Object at all then??

Comment: I don't know anything about Immutable but the docs shows an immutable object property cannot be changed while in you example you are not changing a property but mutating a normal JavaScript array that happens to be the value..

Comment: @Syl You are right! that's what I figured, is there a point in such immutable structure? when you can modify its internal objs?

Comment: Perhaps tyou can do `fromJS(obj)` and it will deep replace all with immutable data structures.

Comment: @Sylwester changed the question, and I think you are right about the use of `fromJS()` but not sure. Would be nice to verify that

Comment: @Sylwester just tested `fromJS` it converts the object deeply